# Duplicate Removal Within a String or Across Column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm writing a bunch of URLs and I'm trying to clean them up by removing duplicate words within a string. The problem is the words are separated by slashes and spaces (which will become dashes eventually), which is where I've hit a wall. Here is what the structure of the URL segments look like:

```
Beverages | Drinks      
Beverages | Drinks |    Chocolate Drinks    
Beverages | Drinks |    Chocolate Drinks |  Chocolate Milk

Beverages | Drinks |    Coffee  
Beverages | Drinks |    Coffee |    Iced Coffee
```

Ideally the URLs would be:

```
/beverages/drinks
/beverages/drinks/chocolate
/beverages/drinks/chocolate/milk (the second chocolate removed).

/beverages/drinks/coffee
/beverages/drinks/coffee/iced
```

The formula I used to combine the segments into urls was:

```
=LOWER(M1 & IF(AND(M1<>"",N1 & O1<>""),"/","")& N1 & IF(AND(N1<>"",O1 & P1<>""),"/","") & O1 & IF(AND(O1<>"",P1<>""),"/","") & P1)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

i m assuming you have everything on a single cell right?

i would suggest you split them up, for example if a given path starts with 
/beverages/drinks/....

you can replace spaces with nothing and then split the string by |, so then you can manipulate that array and build your paths. it would be better if at least you split the original string into 2 (the constant-->beverages-drinks; and the variable) and then adapt my codes to that.

```
Range("b1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Range("a1"))
Range("b1") = Replace(Range("b1").Value, " ", "")
yourarray = Split(Range("b1").Value, "|")
```

let me know if it works or you have your data in a different way.

Comment: Yeah - I ended up doing something similar by splitting the words by space and then running a remove duplicate macro. Then I merged them back together with a formula that kept the multiple word phrases within the same set of slashes. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If each "part" is a single word, then you could do process each line and remove the duplicate words and extra spaces; then join the results with the slash.  However, if some of the "parts" consist of two words (e.g. `beverages | drinks | root beer`, then we need to rethink the algorithm.  As a minimum, you might need some kind of lookup table to find the multi-word parts.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub CondenseURLParts()
    Dim colParts As Collection
    Dim colURLs As Collection
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    Dim V1 As Variant, V2 As Variant

'Set source data and results worksheets and range
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 2)

'Get original data
With wsSrc
    vSrc = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
End With

'Process each line and collect unduplicated parts
Set colURLs = New Collection
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc)
    V1 = Split(vSrc(I, 1), "|")
    If UBound(V1) <> -1 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set colParts = New Collection
            For J = 0 To UBound(V1)
                V2 = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(V1(J)))
                For K = 0 To UBound(V2)
                    colParts.Add V2(K), CStr(V2(K))
                Next K
            Next J
        On Error GoTo 0
        colURLs.Add colParts
    End If
Next I

'Create Results array
ReDim vRes(0 To colURLs.Count, 1 To 1)
vRes(0, 1) = "URL Parts"
For I = 1 To UBound(vRes)
    ReDim V1(1 To colURLs(I).Count)
        For J = 1 To UBound(V1)
            V1(J) = colURLs(I)(J)
        Next J
    vRes(I, 1) = "/" & Join(V1, "/")
Next I

'Write the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

---

Comment: I ended up splitting the words by space and then running a remove duplicate macro. Then I merged them back together with a formula that kept the multiple word phrases within the same set of slashes. Thanks for the help!